# Accessing Attributes of a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I am writing a QML application that loads and displays images, I have a central frame that show the image the user is currently looking at as well as a sidebar that lets the user select images. What I am having trouble with is getting the information about what the currently selected item is in the sidebar (`ListView`).

Additionally, I am having trouble accessing the `sourceChanged` signal in the `delegate` for the `ListView` and therefore can't update the images in the list without the user scrolling down and then back up to force them to reload. Is there any easy way to access these attributes even though they are nested within a `ListView`?

Here is the code for my `ListView`. The issue is that I want to be able to access the `Image` from outside of the `ListView` in order to send a `sourceChanged` signal but I'm not sure how you would access a specific item in the list.

```
//The list of frames that have been loaded
ListView {
    id: frameList
    anchors {top: parent.top; bottom: parent.bottom; left: frameViewer.right; leftMargin: 5; topMargin: 5}
    spacing: 5
    width:300
    height: parent.height

    Component {
        id: frameDelegate

        Rectangle {
            id: wrapper
            anchors {horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter}
            height: 300
            width: 300
            //If there is an image in that space and if it's selected, highlight it
            color: frames[number] === undefined ? "white" : wrapper.ListView.view.currentIndex === index ? "yellow" : "white"
            Image {
                id: image
                height: 280
                width: 280
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "image://images/" + frames[number]
            }

            MouseArea {
                height: 280
                width: 280
                anchors.fill: image
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: frames[index] === undefined ? console.log(""): wrapper.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: frameModel
        ListElement {
            number: 0
        }
        ListElement {
            number: 1
        }
        ListElement {
            number: 2
        }
        ListElement {
            number: 3
        }
        ListElement {
            number: 4
        }
        ListElement {
            number: 5
        }
    }

    model: frameModel
    delegate: frameDelegate
    focus: true
}
```

Comment: You have to show us your code. Also, "What I am having trouble with is" needs to be expanded upon... why are you having trouble with it? What have you done and what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the issue, although I may not have done it in the best way possible.

My solution is to create a signal `newFrame` in the window which would be sent every time a new frame is loaded. Then I use a `Connections` in the `Image` to update the `source`, every time that signal is sent.

```
signal newFrame()

//Stores all the fileURLs
function loadImages()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < fileDialog.fileUrls.length; i++)
    {
        var exists = false
        for(var j = 0; j < frames.length; j++)
        {
            if(frames[j] === fileDialog.fileUrls[i])
            {
                exists = true
            }
        }
        if(exists == false)
        {
            if(frames == [])
            {
                frames = fileDialog.fileUrls[i]
            }
            else
            {
               frames.push(fileDialog.fileUrls[i])
            }
            frame.sourceChanged(frame.source)
            newFrame()

        }
    }

}

Component
{
    id: frameDelegate
    Rectangle
    {
        id: wrapper
        anchors {horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter}
        height: 300
        width: 300
        //If there is an image in that space and if it's selected, highlight it
        color: frames[number] === undefined ? "white" : wrapper.ListView.view.currentIndex === index ? "yellow" : "white"
        Image
        {
            id: image
            height: 280
            width: 280
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "image://images/" + frames[number]
            Connections {
                target: window
                onNewFrame: {
                    image.source = "image://images/" + frames[number]
                }
            }
        }

        MouseArea
        {
            height: 280
            width: 280
            anchors.fill: image
            hoverEnabled: true
            onClicked: {frames[index] === undefined ? console.log(""): wrapper.ListView.view.currentIndex = index; frame.sourceChanged(frame.source)}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't provide all your code but, if I got what you are trying to do, I think you have overcomplicated the problem. Consider [this approach](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=uMN7n5nk): it is simple and compact and it should also work if you change the array since the list dimension is defined over the array size. Also, the model is substituted by a number since you just need the indexing and thus the `number` property is plain redundant.